# Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'customerid' at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on my project for school and is now stuck on this problem that I hope someone here my point me in the right direction.

I am designing a booking system which uses a web front and MySQL database. I have a few tables: Customers, Seats, Price, Booking and Screening. I am trying to insert data into the booking table from the other tables using there primary keys. however I keep getting the following error message: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'customerid' at row 1
I have search every where but doesn't seem to get any solution. I have copied my code below.

```
<?php                           
$customerid=$_POST['customerid'];
$screeningid=$_POST['screeningid'];
$seatid=$_POST['seatid'];
$priceid=$_POST['priceid'];
$status=$_POST['status'];

$query = "INSERT INTO `booking`(bookingid, customerid, screeningid,        seatid,     priceid, bookingdate, status) 
VALUES(NULL, '". mysql_real_escape_string($customerid)."', '".   mysql_real_escape_string($screeningid)."', '". mysql_real_escape_string($seatid)."','". mysql_real_escape_string($priceid)."', 'DateTime()', '". mysql_real_escape_string($status)."')";

$result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

// if successfully insert data into database, displays   message "Successful". 
if($result)
{
echo "<p>success</p>"; 
echo "<BR>"; 
} 
else 
    { 
echo mysql_error();
}
?>
```

This is my Form:

```
<div id="content"> 
        <h2>Enter Booking Details Below</h2>   

        <form name="reg_form" action="bookingecho.php?action=add type=booking" onsubmit="return validate_reg()" method="POST" >
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td>Customer</td>
            <td> <select name="customerid">             
        <?php
            //Perform database query
            $query = ("SELECT * FROM customers
                ORDER BY customerid DESC");

            $result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die (mysql_error());  
            // populate the select options with the results

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                {
                //extract column
                $customerid = $row['customerid'];
                $fname = $row['fname'];
                $lname = $row['lname'];
                $telephone = $row['telephone'];
                //use
                echo "<option value>$customerid $fname $lname $telephone</option>";
                }                   
        ?>
            </select></td></tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Screening</td>
            <td> <select name="screeningid">                
        <?php
            //Perform database query
            $query = ("SELECT * FROM screening");

            $result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die (mysql_error());  
            // populate the select options with the results

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                {
                //extract column
                $screeningid = $row['screeningid'];
                $day = $row['day'];
                $screeningdate = $row['screeningdate'];
                $filmtitle = $row['filmtitle'];


                //use
                echo "<option value>$screeningid $day $screeningdate $filmtitle</option>";
                }                   
        ?>
        </select></td></tr>             

        <tr>
            <td>Seat</td>
            <td> <select name="seatid">             
        <?php

            //Perform database query
            $query = ("SELECT seats.seatid, seats.seatnumber, seats.seatclass
                    FROM seats
                    WHERE seatid 
                    NOT IN (SELECT seatid FROM booking 
                    WHERE screeningid = '$screeningid')
                    ORDER BY `Seats`.`seatid` ASC");

            $result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die (mysql_error());  
            // populate the select options with the results

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                {
                //extract column
                $seatid = $row['seatid'];
                $seatnumber = $row['seatnumber'];
                $seatclass = $row['seatclass'];


                //use
                echo "<option value>$seatid $seatnumber $seatclass</option>";
                }                   
        ?>
        </select></td></tr> 

        <tr>
            <td>Concession</td>
            <td> <select name="priceid">                
        <?php
            //Perform database query
            $query = ("SELECT * FROM price");

            $result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die (mysql_error());  
            // populate the select options with the results

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                {
                //extract column
                $priceid = $row['priceid'];
                $concession = $row['concession'];
                $cost = $row['cost'];


                //use
                echo "<option value>$priceid $concession $cost</option>";
                }                   
        ?>
        </select></td></tr>

        <tr>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>
            <input type= radio name="status" value="Booked"> Booked
            <input type= radio name="status" value="Reserved"> Reserved

        </td>
        </tr>
        </select></td></tr>
        </table>            

              <p align="center">                     
                 <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id= "submit" value="Add"/></td>
                 <input type="reset" value="Reset Form">
              </p>


        </form>     
    </div>
```

Comment: So what datatype is `customerid`? And what is the value of `$_POST['customerid']`?

Comment: customerid is interger

Comment: And the value of the value of `$_POST['customerid']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `intval()` for integer values.
Use `mysql_real_escape_string` on strings, Never for integers.
Single quotes around integer values in a mySQL query is optional.
Because `intval()` guarantees `$customerid` is an integer value, the quotes are not necessary and will never generate an error.

I have only included the two lines of code directly related to your customer id.  The same likely applies to the other values as well.

```
$customerid=intval($_POST['customerid']);

$query = "INSERT INTO `booking`
(`bookingid`, `customerid`, `screeningid`,`seatid`,`priceid`, `bookingdate`, `status`)  
VALUES(NULL,$customerid,'$screeningid','$seatid','$priceid',CURDATE(),'$status')";
```

Change:

```
<input name="status" value="Booked" type="radio"> Booked
<input name="status" value="Reserved" type="radio"> Reserved
```

To:

```
<input name="status" value="1" type="radio"> Booked
<input name="status" value="2" type="radio"> Reserved
```

Always submit integer values greater then zero whenever possible.  They are easy to validate.  To get the text back:

```
$statuses = array('unknown','booked','reserved')
$strStatus = $statuses[$status];
```

### UPDATE FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT ERROR

A CONSTRAINT ERROR says you do not have a customer record for the added booking table.  Or the foreign key is wrong.  The foreign key is not needed.

You could combine the customer add, lookup and booking INSERT at the same time.

Rather than some sort of login to create or retrieve the customer record get the booking then during the last step in the booking process just ask for the phone number. Personally I do not care if someone were to query the system with my phone number and found out which seat I have. Some might.  But asking for a a login in before getting the booking is a nuisance and a road block to finalizing the booking.

What I did was add the security ID

If they want to secure their seats with a password let it be their choice.

If the record does not exist, then ask for their name AFTER the seats are booked.

```
//$customerid = intval($_POST['customerid']);
$screeningid = intval($_POST['screeningid']);
$seatid = intval($_POST['seatid']);
$priceid = intval($_POST['priceid']);
$status = intval($_POST['status']);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$telephone = intval(preg_replace('/[^D]/','',$_POST['telephone']));

//must have UNIQUE Index on `telephone`

$sql = "INSERT INTO `customer` (`customerid`,`fname`, `lname`, `telephone`)
VALUES(NULL,'', '', $telephone)";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_insert_id()){
  $customerid = mysql_insert_id();
}
else{
  list($customerid, $fname`, $lname,$id) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query(
  "SELECT `customerid`,`fname`, `lname`, `telephone`,`id` 
   FROM `customer` WHERE  `telephone`=$telephone"),MYSQL_NUM);
}

$query = "INSERT INTO `booking` 
(`bookingid`, `customerid`, `screeningid`,`seatid`,`priceid`, `bookingdate`, `status`)
VALUES(NULL,$customerid,$screeningid,$seatid,$priceid,CURDATE(),$status)";

echo <<<EOT
<p>Your seats are booked.</p>
<form action="update.php" method="post">
  <label>Last:</label>
  <input type="text" name="lname" value="$lname" />
  <br/>
  <label>First:</label>
  <input type="text" name="fname" value="$fname" />
  <br/>
  <label>Phone:</label>
  <input type="tel" name="telephone" value="$telephone" />
  <br/>
  <p class="footnote">Security ID is optional</p>
  <label>Security ID:</label>
  <input type="text" name="id" value="$id" />
  <br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="$telephone" />
  <br/>
  <div class="footnote">

    If you want to keep your booking secure then enter a security id.
    <br>If blank, no security ID will be necessary to retrieve your seats in the future.
    <br/>This can be any number (e.g. PIN) word, or any characters.
    <br/>Maximum 16 characters.</p>
    <p>Do NOT use an existing high security password (e.g. your banking password)</p>

    <h4>If you would like your seats sent to you via text,<br/>Select your mobile carrier<br/>This will also verify you entered the correct phone number</h4> 
  </div>
  <label>Mobile Carrier</label>
  <select>
    <option value="">No Text / Land Line</option>
    <option value="@message.alltel.com">Alltel</option>
    <option value="@paging.acswireless.com">Ameritech</option>
    <option value="@mmode.com">ATT Wireless</option>
    <option value="@bellsouth.cl">Bellsouth</option>
    <option value="@myboostmobile.com">Boost</option>
    <option value="@mobile.celloneusa.com">CellularOne</option>
    <option value="@mobile.mycingular.com">Cingular</option>
    <option value="@sms.edgewireless.com">Edge Wireless</option>
    <option value="@mymetropcs.com">Metro PCS</option>
    <option value="@messaging.nextel.com">Nextel</option>
    <option value="@mobile.celloneusa.com">O2</option>
    <option value="@mobile.celloneusa.com">Orange</option>
    <option value="@qwestmp.com">Qwest</option>
    <option value="@pcs.rogers.com">Rogers Wireless</option>
    <option value="@messaging.sprintpcs.com">Sprint PCS</option>
    <option value="@teleflip.com">Teleflip</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="@msg.telus.com">Telus Mobility</option>
    <option value="@email.uscc.net">US Cellular</option>
    <option value="@vtext.com">Verizon</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
</form>
EOT;
```

### FORM SNIPPET

```css
label {
  width: 5em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
.footnote {
  margin: .5em 0 .5em 5em;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  margin: 1em 6em;
}
h4 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Your seats are booked.</p>
<form action="update.php" method="post">
  <label>Last:</label>
  <input type="text" name="lname" value="$lname" />
  <br/>
  <label>First:</label>
  <input type="text" name="fname" value="$fname" />
  <br/>
  <label>Phone:</label>
  <input type="tel" name="telephone" value="$telephone" />
  <br/>
  <p class="footnote">Security ID is optional</p>
  <label>Security ID:</label>
  <input type="text" name="id" value="$id" />
  <br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="$telephone" />
  <br/>
  <div class="footnote">

    If you want to keep your booking secure then enter a security id.
    <br>If blank, no security ID will be necessary to retrieve your seats in the future.
    <br/>This can be any number (e.g. PIN) word, or any characters.
    <br/>Maximum 16 characters.</p>
    <p>Do NOT use an existing high security password (e.g. your banking password)</p>

    <h4>If you would like your seats sent to you via text,<br/>Select your mobile carrier<br/>This will also verify you entered the correct phone number</h4> 
  </div>
  <label>Mobile Carrier</label>
  <select>
    <option value="">No Text / Land Line</option>
    <option value="@message.alltel.com">Alltel</option>
    <option value="@paging.acswireless.com">Ameritech</option>
    <option value="@mmode.com">ATT Wireless</option>
    <option value="@bellsouth.cl">Bellsouth</option>
    <option value="@myboostmobile.com">Boost</option>
    <option value="@mobile.celloneusa.com">CellularOne</option>
    <option value="@mobile.mycingular.com">Cingular</option>
    <option value="@sms.edgewireless.com">Edge Wireless</option>
    <option value="@mymetropcs.com">Metro PCS</option>
    <option value="@messaging.nextel.com">Nextel</option>
    <option value="@mobile.celloneusa.com">O2</option>
    <option value="@mobile.celloneusa.com">Orange</option>
    <option value="@qwestmp.com">Qwest</option>
    <option value="@pcs.rogers.com">Rogers Wireless</option>
    <option value="@messaging.sprintpcs.com">Sprint PCS</option>
    <option value="@teleflip.com">Teleflip</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="@msg.telus.com">Telus Mobility</option>
    <option value="@email.uscc.net">US Cellular</option>
    <option value="@vtext.com">Verizon</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
</form>
```

Comment: seems to sort it however now I am getting:    Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cinema_booking`.`booking`, CONSTRAINT `booking_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customerid`) REFERENCES `customers` (`customerid`))

Comment: I never use Foreign Keys so I cannot help much.  Either remove the key or the constraint from the table's index, or fix the query or table structure so the child record is created/updated meet the constraining criteria. If you are not familiar with with foreign keys, try exporting your database (structure only) and look at the export document.

Comment: I have searched everywhere and not found a solution on how to sort out the foreign key constraint problem. I have also rechecked my tables and all seems ok with them. really don't know I am missing

Comment: Why do you have a foreign key?

Comment: without the foreign key I will not be able to insert or update bookings. and when I remove the foreign key all I see in my booking table are zeros.

Comment: You just handle the management of the booking table with SQL.  I do not have your database schema, so I have no idea what you are saying.

Comment: Foreign keys only stop you from violating the constraints imposed by the foreign key on INSERT UPDATE and DELETE.  It does not have anything to do with accessing the data.  It appears you are trying to add a new or change the `customerid` in the booking table to a value that does not exist in the customer table.

Comment: Here is my schema: (don't now how to add an image so I will explain as best as possible)   I have 5 tables. Table 1 has customer details i.e. cust_id int 11 PK, fname, lname, telephone,  Table 2 has screening details i.e. screenid, int 11 PK, screening date, day, film title. Table 3 has price_id int 11 PK, concession, cost. Table 4 has Seats i.e. seat_id int 11 PK, seat class, seat number. and Table 5 has booking i.e booking_id int 11, booking date, customer_id int 11 FK, screening_id int 11 FK, seat_id, price_id int 11 FK, Bookingstatus.

Comment: Cheers its now working. I have also managed to change the mysql to mysqli for good measures.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means you are getting an "empty string" (`''`) for `customerid`, which simply means that your first chunk of code is not getting any value at all for that field when the form is submitted.

Here is the problem:

```
echo "<option value>$customerid $fname $lname $telephone</option>";
```

The values between `<option>` and `</option>` are what will be displayed to the end-user, but they will not be *submitted* with your form, which means they won't be available to that first chunk of code.

To submit the customerid, you have to put it into the `value` part:

```
echo "<option value=$customerid>$customerid $fname $lname $telephone</option>";
```

Comment: That is correct but it does not address how horrible a method it is to do a customer ID lookup when customer tables tend get large for successful businesses. .Not only that, how many customers would want to see their name an phone number on a ticket site? We don't intentionally do things that work only for unsuccessful businesses by making them unsuccessful. I recommended he replace that with asking for the phone number to do the lookup.  But you probably down voted me before you got that far, thanks.  The reason for the emphasis on intval was because the prior answer gave poor advice.

Comment: Well, this is for school. I feel like getting into all of that was probably beyond the scope of the lesson, and was definitely outside the scope of the question, which was simply, "Why am I getting this error message?"

Answer (score -2):

You placed apostrophes around `$customerid` (and other non-string values) when it is actually an integer inside your database. Delete the apostropes (') around all values that are meant to be integers in your database (I have a feeling that is the case for many of your variables). Also please organize your code because it was extremely difficult to look at it without crying :)

```
<?php

    $customerid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['customerid']);
    $screeningid=$_POST['screeningid'];
    $seatid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['seatid']);
    $priceid=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['priceid']);
    $status=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status']);


    $query = "INSERT INTO `booking`(bookingid, customerid, 
    screeningid, seatid, priceid, bookingdate, status) 
    VALUES (NULL, ". $customerid.", ". $screeningid.", ".     
    $seatid.", ".$priceid.", 'DateTime()', '".$status."')";

    $result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    // if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
    if($result)
    {
        echo "<p>success</p><br>"; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
         echo mysql_error();
    }

?>
```

Also note, `DateTime()` is a php function, not an SQL command. I left it in the previous code but be aware that you should fix that error.

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: If you remove the single quotes without fist validating the value is an integer (in this case) it may create an error where the query fails rather than with the quote marks only a warning and the other fields data contents are not lost.  mysql_real_escape_string should never be used on integer values.